# R - invalid 'sep' value: must be one byte

Tags: r, read.csv

I have a simple CSV file which was created in R using

```
write.csv(exportChoice, file="exportChoice.csv")
```

When I read this file using

```
exportChoice <- read.csv(file = "exportChoice.csv", header=TRUE, row.names=1)
```

I get the error message:

```
Error in scan(file, what = "", sep = sep, quote = quote, nlines = 1:
  invalid 'sep' value: must be one byte
```

but I am certain that I only have a single comma separator.

When I open this CSV file in Microsoft Word, I see that my row and column names are surrounded by quotation marks, for some reason. Could this be the problem with reading the file? How do I solve it?

Comment: Having quotes around each value is normal; though not required for basic strings, anything with an embedded comma requires quotes around the value to differentiate between a mid-string comma and a field-separating comma. Even with that, having quote marks around values without commas is nothing to worry about, I see it all the time. We are unlikely to be able to help without having a *reproducible question*, please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269, https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve, and https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info.

Comment: Try adding the argument `encoding = "UTF-8"` inside your `read.csv` call.